# My Apache server wont run even after successful build on Jenkins using Docker

Tags: bash, dockerfile, dockerhub

I connected my aws instance, slave to my jenkins master. The Ubuntu slave has Docker and JDK installed. Now, I have a project in Git, I tried to test run by asking my dockerfile to pull a docker image in my dockerhub repository. It is an ubuntu image on which I already had Apache installed and started in the container.

When I build with jenkins, it ends up successful but my apache server doesn't display my test website.

What can I do. I have been on this for 3 days.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM espada1/ubuntu-apache
COPY ./major /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
CMD apachect1 -D FOREGROUND
RUN rm /var/www/html/index.html
```

**Execute Build Command**

```
sudo docker build -t testweb '/home/ubuntu/workspace/workspace/Instance-deploy'
sudo docker run -it -d -p 80:80 testweb
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `CMD apachect1 -D FOREGROUND` instead `CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND`

Note that you have put an `1` (one) instead an `L`